# Haskell function checking if number is odd, without using the odd function

Tags: haskell, list-comprehension, ghc, pattern-guards

Can anyone help me with that? I am trying to write a function checking if an x is odd, without using the odd function.
Like this it does not work but i don't know why.

```
   ugerade :: Integral a => a -> Bool
   ugerade x
    |x elem oddList  = True
    |otherwise = False
    where
     oddList=[x | x<-[1,3..]]
```

Error

```
    Could not deduce (Num t0) arising from the literal ‘1’
from the context (Integral a)
  bound by the type signature for ugerade :: Integral a => a -> Bool
  at /Users/Mauritius/Desktop/Haskell/u02/2-2/funktionen.hs:24:11-33
The type variable ‘t0’ is ambiguous
Relevant bindings include
  oddList :: [t0]
    (bound at /Users/Mauritius/Desktop/Haskell/u02/2-2/funktionen.hs:29:4)
Note: there are several potential instances:
  instance Integral a => Num (GHC.Real.Ratio a)
    -- Defined in ‘GHC.Real’
  instance Num Integer -- Defined in ‘GHC.Num’
  instance Num Double -- Defined in ‘GHC.Float’
  ...plus three others
In the expression: 1
In the expression: [1, 3 .. ]
In a stmt of a list comprehension: x <- [1, 3 .. ]
```

Comment: Is the modulo forbidden as well ?

Comment: no it isn't. but i wanted to do it with a list-comprehension. i don't get the mistake

Comment: `not . even` ? :-) More in the spirit of your effort so far would be `ungerade x = Data.Maybe.fromJust (lookup x (zip [1..] (cycle [True,False])))` which at least terminates for positive `x`.

Comment: i solved it with modulo. did not think about that first but is obviously the easiest way if you do not want to use even

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is in the line

```
x elem oddList
```

which should either say

```
elem x oddList
```

since `elem` is a function `elem :: Eq a => a -> [a] -> Bool`, or

```
x `elem` oddList
```

where you are using backticks to indicate infix function application.

---

Note that your function does not work as you intended. For odd numbers it will eventually return `True` (although it takes a long time for large arguments) but for even numbers it will never return, because the function cannot prove that an even number is never in the list `oddList`.

Also note that writing

```
oddList = [ x | x <- [1,3..] ]
```

is redundant, you could just write

```
oddList = [1,3..]
```

instead, and also writing

```
f x | x `elem` oddList = True
    | otherwise        = False
```

is redundant, where you could just write

```
f x = x `elem` oddList
```

or even

```
f x = x `elem` [1,3..]
```

or

```
f = (`elem` [1,3..])
```

Comment: thanks. That works! At least no error, but it is not terminating either

Comment: just realized.. it will search the list forever